# export pyplot figure to PNG without antialias

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to generate high-resolution raster images from pyplot figures, **without antialias** (why? See below)

Some time ago, on Python 2.7 and Matplotlib 1.5, I worked out two processes for this:

1. `plt.savefig()` to PDF, and then manually import into GIMP at 1200dpi or higher, with anti-alias turned off, and export the result to a PNG.
2. `plt.savefig()` to EPS, and run a small ImageMagick script to convert the result to a non-antialiased png at very high resolution.

Drawback: These processes take either time, create new non-python dependencies or are somewhat awkward to implement (e.g.: the ImageMagick method had to be adapted for almost every machine it was running on).

###### Question:

Is there by now (Python 3.9, matplotlib 3.6) another way to produce a high-res, non-antialiased PNG from a Matplotlib/pyplot figure, that works entirely in Python, without external dependencies or manual labour involved? I haven't found any new suitable arguments for `plt.savefig()`, but maybe there is another way, like some global antialias switch for matplotlib, pyplot or one of the plotting backends?

###### In case you're wondering:

*I'm generating lots of figures from pyplot, in SVG or PDF format. Such vector figures are ideal for printing, viewing at any scale, and even allow me to make manual adjustments or change the layout or labels later, in Inkscape.*

*Sometimes, however, I need to generate raster images for use in applications which can't deal with vector images. I still want them to print sharply (antialiased images don't) and to scale nicely to most reasonable sizes (anti-aliased images don't scale up well). I also find that a 1200dpi non-antialiased image of line art, which produces a 4x antialiased image at 300dpi when scaled down by a factor of 4, actually produces a smaller PNG file than the antialiased scaled-down version -- even in jpeg format[1] -- because it needs a much smaller colour palette.*

[1]: please don't use jpeg for line art, it hurts my eyes!

Comment: What is wrong with saving 1200 dpi in Matplotlib and `mpl.rcParams['text.antialiased'] = False` and turning off anti aliasing for your artists?

Comment: How do I turn off anti-aliasing for everything (axes, ticks, legend, grid ...), without iterating through every object in the figure and turn it off individually (and later finding out what I overlooked...)? Also, I seem to remember that `rcParams` don't affect existing figures, so I would then have to turn off antialiasing for on-screen fonts globally, before creating a figure which I may want to save without antialias, or could the setting be set/unset just for the export operation?

Comment: there is `lines.antialiased` and `patches.antialiased`.  But I really wonder if what you want is to save as PDF or SVG, and rasterize some of your artists (eg a big image or pcolormesh).  Individual artists can be rasterized in a PDF or SVG and overlain with vectors for the rest.

Comment: No. I have pure line art that is ideally encoded as vector graphics, and I need a raster image that approximates vector graphics for cases where I need to use software that can't handle vector graphics. (e.g.: MS Powerpoint ...)